# Near by mobiles not showing when scanning in web bluetooth React PWA

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, web-bluetooth

I was working on PWA with Web Bluetooth. I have two mobiles with Bluetooth enabled near by and I started scanning for nearby bluetooth devices in my pwa application in one mobile. But i was not able to find any scanned result(other bluetooth enable mobile). Is web Bluetooth not able to identify any mobile devices ?

```
navigator.bluetooth
      .requestDevice({
        acceptAllDevices: true
      })
      .then(function (device) {
          console.log("Device")
        return device.gatt.connect();
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        setLatLong([error.message]);
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Bluetooth will only find devices which are currently sending Bluetooth Low Energy advertisements. A mobile device will not normally generate these advertisements even if Bluetooth is enabled.

For example, on Android the [`BluetoothLeAdvertiser`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser) class can be used by an app to configure the device to transmit advertising packets. To actually establish a connection with the device it also has to implement a GATT service using the [`BluetoothGattServer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer) class.

Comment: Thanks for the  answer @Reilly Grant. I have one doubt like, Is there any way that PWA can make a mobile  generate Bluetooth Low Energy advertisements? So that other mobiles can find them.

Comment: Web Bluetooth does not currently specify a way to do this, but we are tracking support for this in our issue tracker. This [closed issue](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/484) has more details.